# custom radiobox sometimes nothing selected

Tags: html, css

I've got the following code:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <h4>Ich interessiere mich für</h4>
    <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline attributes">
        <input type="radio" id="genderFemale" value="f" name="gender" checked>
        <label for="genderFemale"> Damenmode</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="genderMale" value="m" name="gender">
        <label for="genderMale"> Herrenmode</label>
    </div>  
</div>
```

It works fine in general but a radio box just get checked if I click on the radiobox itself and not on the text. Also sometimes suddenly nothing is selected.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Inspect the radio button and check the `-webkit-appearance`, it can usually cause issues...

Comment: Seems to work normally: https://jsfiddle.net/hc91868b/ in Chrome.

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle of the problem? (Including the CSS)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a surrounding display:none